# How can i use gnuplot commands on a shell script

Tags: shell, gnuplot

Hi guys im trying to build a graphic bar with gnuplot.
I have to put the graphic in a png file and then present it in html page.
Im having problems with using the plot command in my script.

If you know to use gnuplot commands in a script, i would aprecciate your help!

Comment: "Im having problems with using the plot command in my script." could you show your current script what yu got so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use gnuplot commands within an interactive shell, on in a shell script:

```
echo 'set term pngcairo; set output "file.png"; plot x' | gnuplot
```

You could also put your commands in `file.gnuplot` and then execute

```
gnuplot file.gnuplot
```

from within your shell script or interactive shell. If instead of writing to file you just want the graph to pop up using the default gnuplot terminal, you can add `-persist`:

```
echo 'plot x' | gnuplot -persist
```

You can also use shell commands inside a gnuplot script or gnuplot interactive session via a `system()` call, but that's a separate topic.